# Eclipse features in Aptana?

Tags: php, eclipse, aptana

It seems to me that most of Eclipse's features do not work for me in Aptana. For instance, when editing Java in Eclipse one can press F3 when the cursor is in a class name to jump to the class definition. When editing PHP files in Aptana this does not work. Is it supposed to work, or must it be enabled somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Aptana advertises that StackOverflow _is_ their support channel: http://aptana.com/support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that your project is not marked as PHP project.

Please try the steps here to change the nature associated with your project:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12452389#ChangingYourProject%27s%22Type%22-ChangingProjectNatures